# MATLAB and DDE LINKS

Tags: matlab

I have developed an trade automator in excel, but its too slow, now im trying to do this in matlab.

One of the links I use to feed my sheets in excel is :

```
=TWSVR|CMA!'0012PETR4;25'
```

I'm trying to receive the same data in matlab, here is what I did:

```
channel = ddeinit('TWSVR','CMA')

lastPetr = ddeadv(channel,'0012PETR4;25',callback)
```

So is this right? Where can I see the data? Where is stored?

This callback function is the one I have to developed to process the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab does not support DDE any more. You can still use DDE, but you may run into troubles.

For data exchange with Excel, I would suggest using `xlsread`, `xlswrite` and `xlsfinfo` instead.

Comment: What do you suggest for realtime data acquiring?

Comment: DDE can be slow for real-time applications anyway. But if you really need it, I can suggest JDDE. I struggled to install it, succeeded and summarized my experience here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19428750/674976.

Comment: texnic, i think this can solve my problem. I'll try and post the results!

Tks Man!